# How to know which app is crashing/throwing exceptions in the background?

Tags: application-error

I'm asking this question as an end user. All of the sudden every x hours an exception is shown on my phone for a brief moment. Something along the lines of could not get x coordinate bla bla. So I guess 1 of my apps needs location permissions but doesn't have them (anymore). I'd like to get rid of the exceptions. However they also show on the home screen, so it's probably a background app. How do I identify which one?

Comment: *an exception is shown on my phone for a brief moment* -- are you seeing a toast, a notification, or a dialog? See if this app is able to log them. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree

Comment: Most apps print exceptions on `logcat`. For seeing these messages you need to enable Developer options and Android Debug Bridge. Then you can connect your phone via USB to a PC with adb/Andrpid SDK installed and see all messages by executing  `adb logcat`.

Comment: @Firelord a pill shaped toast at the bottom

Comment: That is a toast. The convenient method to see historical toasts is that app I mentioned earlier. Non-convenient but more insightful method is `adb logcat`.